# Makefile:10: /usr/pgsql-14/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/pgsql-14/lib/pgxs/src/make

Tags: postgresql, debezium, change-data-capture

I am trying to follow this Debezium installation https://gist.github.com/jpsoroulas/30e9537138ca62a79fe261cff7ceb716

Encounter an issue when running the make command and I am using Rocky Linux.

The tutorial uses Postgres version 9 but I am using Postgres 14 is which could be the reason for the issues encountered.

```
Makefile:10: /usr/pgsql-14/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/pgsql-14/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 5):

```
dnf install postgresql-server-devel
```